# Using TabControl Programmatically

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

If I have a standard TabControl element in Form design view, how can I programmatically create a new Tab with a Button which contains the preset elements such as TextBox, Button etc., or how can I set the Tab to load another Form within itself?

Is this possible?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new tab by calling [`tabControl.TabPages.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection.add.aspx).

You can then add other controls to the `TabPage`'s `Controls` collection.

The simplest way to do this would be to make your own custom control, then add a new instance of the custom control to the `TabPage`, probably docked `Fill`.

For example:

```
var tabPage = tabControl.TabPages.Add("My Custom Tab");
var control = new MyCustomControl();
control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
//Set other properties if you want to.
tabPage.Controls.Add(control);
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. Do I need to include any additional libraries for this example to work?

Comment: No; this is the standard WinForms TabControl.  However, you will need to create a custom control.

Comment: Everything I am reading says that the `tabControl.TabPages.Add(string)` method returns `void`.
Best way I see is to call `tabControl.TabPages[tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1]` after?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly load a `Form` into the content of a `TabPage`.

However, if all your controls are contained within a `UserControl`, the `UserControl` can be placed both inside the tab page and/or in a separate form.